# WCF request without namespace alias

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap, wcf-binding

I have a WCF service that works with a test client generated with SvcUtil.exe.
But my real client is another company that used different technology.

With the generated test client the XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <PostModel xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <model xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SomeName.Models" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <a:Items>
               <a:Item>
                  <a:SomeElement1>SomeValue</a:SomeElement1>
                  <a:SomeElement2>SomeValue</a:SomeElement2>
               </a:Item>
               <a:Item>
                  <a:SomeElement1>SomeValue</a:SomeElement1>
                  <a:SomeElement2>SomeValue</a:SomeElement2>
               </a:Item>
            </a:Items>
            <a:MoreItems>
               <a:MoreItem>
                  <a:SomeElement3>binary</a:SomeElement3>
               </a:MoreItem>
            </a:MoreItems>
         </model>
      </PostModel>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

But the real client sends the xml without alias:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <PostModel xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <model xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SomeName.Models">
            <Items>
               <Item>
                  <SomeElement1>SomeValue</SomeElement1>
                  <SomeElement2>SomeValue</SomeElement2>
               </Item>
               <Item>
                  <SomeElement1>SomeValue</SomeElement1>
                  <SomeElement2>SomeValue</SomeElement2>
               </Item>
            </Items>
            <MoreItems>
               <MoreItem>
                  <SomeElement3>binary</SomeElement3>
               </MoreItem>
            </MoreItems>
         </model>
      </PostModel>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The result is that the model that I receive in the endpoint is NULL. 
If I catch the request in fiddler and edit it, add nothing but the alias for the model namespace and add it to the child-elements it works.

Is there a solution for this problem, as far as I know the XML that the client sends is valid XML, aliases are not mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the test client XML and the real client XML lies in the [namespace](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp) of the element `model`.  From the test client:

```
  <PostModel xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
     <model xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SomeName.Models" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

This defines an element with local name "model".  It has no namespace prefix so exists in the default namespace.  However, it does not define a default namespace for itself -- instead it defines namespaces with prefixes `"a"` and `"i"`.  Thus it belongs in whatever default namespace its parent hierarchy defines, in this case `"http://tempuri.org/"` from its immediate parent.

In the real client's XML, the `model` element again has no prefix but **does** have its own default namespace declaration:

```
  <PostModel xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
     <model xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SomeName.Models">
```

Thus `model` falls into the namespace `"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SomeName.Models"` rather than the parent's default namespace.

All the child elements of `model` are in the same namespace in both XML versions.  It's only the `model` element itself which is inconsistent.

This inconsistency would explain the null model in the endpoint.

Comment: Thx allot, this was the problem, good explanation. I solved this by changing the namespace of PostModel to the same namespace as model.   And let the client regenerate the code using the WSDL.